# Node .on method firing too many times

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an Electron app that presents a directory listing to the user. When the user clicks a button my interface script, interface.js, clears the container div and sends a message to main.js. On receiving the message, main.js scans the directory into an array of filenames and returns the array to interface.js as a response. Interface.js uses a .on method that fires when the response is received and updates the container div with the contents of the array.

This is my first real attempt at using Node, and as far as interface behaviour went everything worked brilliantly! Wonderful, it's only been a few hours and I'm already loving Node!

However, while debugging/stress testing I printed the returned array within the .on method to the console and noticed some strange behaviour. The first time the user clicks the button, the .on method runs once (verified by one message to the console). The second time the user clicks, the method runs twice (verified by two messages to the console); the third time it runs three times and so on.

The function in main.js that scans the directory only runs once per click, so the issue must be within inteface.js.

My code for main.js and interface.js:

main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

...

ipcMain.on( 'list-directory', ( event, directory ) => {
    var files = fs.readdirSync( directory );
    event.sender.send( 'list-directory-reply', files );
});
```

interface.js

```
var { ipcRenderer, remote } = require( 'electron' );  
var main = remote.require( "./main.js" );

...

button.addEventListener('click', function(){ showDialogue( this ); }, false );

...

showDialogue( select ) {
    // clear the dialogue
    // some other stuff
    ipcRenderer.send( 'list-directory', './files/documents/' );
    ipcRenderer.on( 'list-directory-reply', function( event, contents ) {
        console.log( contents );
        if ( contents.length > 0 ) {
            // add contents to the dialogue
        }
    } );
}
```

The code is adapted from a tutorial on the Electron website.

Why does `ipcRenderer.on` run multiple times? Is it possible that it's bound to something every time the button is clicked, and thus runs as many times as past clicks? I put a print statement inside the event listener function, and inside the `showDialogue` function before the `ipcRenderer` stuff, but they both only printed once per click so the repeats are definitely only coming from `ipcRenderer.on`.

Comment: You are subscribing to `ipcRenderer.on` after every button click which is causing multiple subscriptions. Try to define the `ipcRenderer.on` event handler outside click event and it should work fine.

Comment: @planet_hunter brilliant! Works perfectly. Please add as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are subscribing to `ipcRenderer.on` after every button click which is causing multiple subscriptions. Try to define the `ipcRenderer.on` event handler outside click event and it should work fine.

Something like this -

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(){ showDialogue( this ); }, false );


ipcRenderer.on( 'list-directory-reply', function( event, contents ) {
    // ipcRenderer event handler
});

showDialogue(select) {
    ipcRenderer.send( 'list-directory', './files/documents/' );
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the same problem for me, but generally the same. On reworking to accommodate the deprecated/missing `remote` module, my rendering code ended up responding to a menu event which in turn responded to a file open event.

Answer (score 5):

As @planet_hunter mentioned, you are setting up a listener every time `showDialogue()` is called.  You need to remove the listener or move the listener outside of the calling function.

However, I find a cleaner solution is to use the `.once` command.  This behaves like `.on`, but instead of manually having to remove the `.on` listener (which you haven't done) it removes itself.

```
showDialogue( select ) {
    // clear the dialogue
    // some other stuff
    ipcRenderer.send( 'list-directory', './files/documents/' );
    ipcRenderer.once( 'list-directory-reply', function( event, contents ) {
        console.log( contents );
        if ( contents.length > 0 ) {
            // add contents to the dialogue
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Though `once` can be a possible solution in this case, it is always better to keep the event handlers in place before your code comes into the action. As an example, in this case, chances of missing first `'list-directory-reply'` event are high as we are invoking the `list-directory` event first (which is triggering `list-directory-reply` event) but subscribing to `list-directory-reply` event later.

Comment: @planet_hunter What about if you need to process the argument value passed through the initial function call within the ipcRenderer reply code, would it be okay to use the `.once` method?  For example, using the code directly above, assume the `select` argument was needed in the `ipcRenderer` reply code.  Funneling the argument through main process and back to render process seems a bit messy.

Comment: @skaz Sometimes it the event is fired multiple times. I'm not able to solve the issue. I would be a great help if you could just help in this case. Here's the ticket [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906065/electron-js-event-is-firing-multiple-times?noredirect=1#comment113006699_63906065]