# How to prevent multiplication of ipcRenderer listenters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, electron, ipc

I have a button in my react application that needs to do something 1 time every time it's clicked. Currently, when clicked, the listener seems to multiply.

Here is brief example of the code that I'm using:

```js
// In App.js
const App = () => {
    const buttonHandler = () => {
        api.myApi.rendererToMain();
        api.myApi.mainToRenderer();
    };
    return (
        <div>
          <Button cb={buttonHandler} />
        </div>
    );
};

// In Button.js
const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" onClick={ (e) => { props.cb() }}>Send Ping</button>
    )
};


// In main.js
ipcMain.on('async', (e, msg) => {
    console.log(msg); // print ping
    e.reply('async_response', 'pong');
});

// In preload.js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
    myApi: {
        rendererToMain: () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('async', 'ping');
        },
        mainToRenderer: () => {
            ipcRenderer.on('async_response', (e, msg) => {
                console.log(msg);
            });
        },
    },
});
```

When I run the electron app, I have a terminal for the Main process open, and devTools open for output from the renderer. Currently, when the button is pressed 3 times, the result looks like:

```
// In the browserWindow devTools console
pong
(2)pong
(5)pong

// In the Main process console
ping
ping
ping
```

The desired output is only different for the renderer console:

```
pong
pong
pong
```

**My attempted solution**

My first attempt at solving this on my own, after some stackoverflow research, was to try and remove the ipcRenderer listener for the "async_response" channel. All attempts to do this resulted in no output in the renderer console, and all 3 expected pings in the Main process console.

For example:

```js
// Change made in preload.js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
    myApi: {
        rendererToMain: () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('async', 'ping');
        },
        mainToRenderer: () => {
            ipcRenderer.on('async_response', (e, msg) => {
                console.log(msg); // With below change, this does nothing.
            });
            // Attempt to remove the listener now?
            // Seems to remove the listener before any output logged.
            ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('async_response');
        },
    },
});
```

If anyone could help me understand where and how to stop the listeners from multiplying, I would be eternally grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sleep, I realized that my search was too narrow. I found that the `ipcRenderer.on()` method was being subscribed to an additional time each time the button was pressed, as per the concepts in this post: [Node .on method firing too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111151/node-on-method-firing-too-many-times)

Understanding this, I made the following change to my code, such that the call to the `ipcRenderer.on()` method only occurred once:

```js
// In App.js
const App = () => {
    const buttonHandler = () => {
        api.myApi.rendererToMain();
        // api.myApi.mainToRenderer(); <- Removed this call to the ipcRenderer.on()
    };
    return (
        <div>
          <Button cb={buttonHandler} />
        </div>
    );
};

// In Button.js
const Button = (props) => {
    const callbackHandler = () => {
        props.cb();
    };
    // Subscribe to listener on component construction
    api.myApi.mainToRenderer(); 
    return (
        <button type="button" onClick={ (e) => { callbackHandler() }}>Send Ping</button>
    )
};
```

These changes result in exactly the expected behavior. After three clicks of the button, I see in the renderer console:

```
(3)pong
```

Going to leave this unanswered for a time. I'm definitely open to comments about my fix and implementation all around.